Ruby setter-methods: Is the equal-character (=) a convention or functionality?
Taken this class as a example:
class House
  def initialize(color, size)
    @color = color
    @size = size
  end

  def color
    @color
  end
  # Is the = part of the syntax or a convention?
  def color=(color)
    @color = color
  end
end

Is the equal '=' at the end of the setter-method a convention, like the '!' or the '?'?
Or does is add functionality?

It is “only” a convention, like ending methods returning a boolean with ? or adding a ! when there is a less dangerous counterpart method.
You could define the setter method with (Java style)
def set_color(color)
  @color = color
end

or even using Unicode
def (color)
  @color = color
end

and it wouldn't make any difference at runtime.
Btw in this example, you could also use
attr_writer :color

See attr_writer, attr_reader, and attr_accessor.

One minor difference is that assignment expressions return the assigned value, regardless of the assignment method’s return value, allowing for chained assignments.

...and in the case of method invocation, regardless of whether or not assignment actually occurs.
